# SES from AWS does not work with Django due to unverified Email

Tags: python, django, amazon-ses

I tried to sign up on Deployed Django app as a sample user but Server Error (500) comes up.

Here is error log

```
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.MessageRejected: An error occurred (MessageRejected) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: webmaster@localhost
2020-07-27 12:32:52,406 [ERROR] /home/app_admin/venv_private_diary/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py(Line:154)      "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.0" 500 27
```

In the error message "webmaster@localhost" indicates that Django app sends default email address, hence I had added this statement to settings.py.

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my@emailaddress.com'
```

but still, the same error message came up.
where should I check??

Comment: i am facing same issue, did you get the solution?

Comment: I had to set two new vars to get rid of this error.
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it was a simple one: I had not set all the django-ses variables correctly in settings.py, specifically the ones that define the AWS region you are sending from:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'

# These are optional -- if they're set as environment variables they won't
# need to be set here as well
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-ID'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY'

# Additionally, if you are not using the default AWS region of us-east-1,
# you need to specify a region, like so:
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

This was taken from [the django-SES github page](https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses).

By default, emails will be sent from AWS region `US-East-1`, as stated in your error, so I would guess that this was your problem.